# Where can I find a copy of Iran's proposal pertaining to Palestine to U.N. Security Council on November 1, 2019?

Tags: united-nations, iran, palestine, reference-request

From the official [Khamenei.ir's *"Which final solution?"*](https://english.khamenei.ir/news/7592/Which-final-solution)

> It appears that the uproar and the responses of the American and Zionist authorities and their mercenaries are for the most part motivated by the fact that they do not have anything to say in the face of the Islamic Republic’s democratic solution and its firm logical basis more than by their long-held grudge and animosity toward the Islamic Republic of Iran and Imam Khamenei as the leader of the Resistance camp. **(The complete proposal was presented by Iran’s permanent representative to the U.N. Security Council on November 1, 2019.)**

Is this "complete proposal" hosted or archived anywhere publicly by the U.N. Security Council? Is there an authoritative (UN) source on the actual content of the proposal? It seems likely the proposal wasn't accepted as a resolution, and [I can't find the text of proposals on the UN Security Council's english site](https://www.un.org/unispal/data-collection/security-council/?wpv_view_count=237043&wpv_sort_orderby=field-wpcf-document-date&wpv_sort_order=asc&wpv_sort_orderby_as=numeric&wpv_paged=30).

Comment: Much as the title or content of the proposal may be questionable, this reference request asking where the proposal may be found is not. In its current form, the question is on-topic. Comments that seek to discredit the OP for researching the proposal may be deleted. I will open a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124631/israelipalestinian-conflict) on the broader conflict where users can discuss the conflict as well as the contents of this proposal.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The complete proposal was presented in an annex to a letter from Iran's permanent representative to the UN Secretary-General. The letter and annex are hosted on the UN's website with document number [S/2019/862](https://undocs.org/en/S/2019/862). The letter reads:

> It is a source of grave concern that, after more than seven decades,
> the question of Palestine is still unresolved and the international
> community has failed to settle this chronic complicated crisis. I
> attach herewith (see annex), for your kind attention, the text of a
> plan, received from the Secretariat of the International Conference on
> Palestine, concerning a national referendum in the Territory of
> Palestine.
> I should be grateful if you would have the present letter
> and its annex circulated as a document of the Security Council.
>
> (Signed) Majid Takht Ravanchi
> Ambassador
> Permanent Representative

The annex includes the plan, entitled *The Plan for Holding a National Referendum in the Territory of Palestine*.